# trouble with custom array and selection

Tags: delphi

I will start this over what am trying to do is convert the array into a dymanic array that will get the stations from a listview in place of a preset array

```
const
  urls: array[0..1] of AnsiString = ( // preset stream URLs
    'http://www.radioparadise.com/m3u/mp3-128.m3u', 'http://www.radioparadise.com/m3u/mp3-32.m3u');
```

I have no code pre done so there no code to show or give am mostly asking for help in how to do it or pointed in the right direction.

Comment: The code you've posted does give *access errors*, because it won't even compile. It's not even close to real code. Please [edit] your question and post the **actual code** you've tried that isn't working for you. (We're not going to keep asking you every time you post here to edit to provide real information. Please read [ask] and [mcve].)

Comment: The code you've posted **cannot** generate that message, because **it will not compile**. Please [edit] to post **your real code**, as I've asked you to do already. **Real code** that will compile, as the link to [mcve] tells you how to do. Not code you made up for this post, but your **real  code that will compile and run**. `urls: array of AnsiString = (Items.SubItems[i]);` is **not valid Delphi code, and it will not compile**.

Comment: This >> `urls: array of AnsiString`, i think that you want say that is a local variable, but is located in a wrong place on you code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  urls: array of string;

...
SetLength(urls, ListView.Items.Count);
for i := 0 to Items.Count-1 do 
begin 
  // assuming the URL is in the first subitem
  urls[i] := ListView.Items[i].SubItems[0];
end;
...
```

Then you can use `urls[index]` when needed.

Comment: While this answer is clearlycorrect, it's a shame you posted it before the poster edited the question. You've removed all incentive for them to do so, and taught them that even though they're not willing to cooperate and post the actual problem code, they can just continue to post garbage here and still get someone to give them the solution. It's a poor lesson to teach a new user.

Comment: thanks ken for pointing out the errors but some times I dont always get what you mean when I post i do try and make its easy clear as I can I dont honestly mean to post garbage and am willing to cooperate fully but I have a learning disabilitie so typing and reading is not my strong point so it may seam like am just not cooperating but its just because i dont really understand sorry agen man and Remy thanks for the reply

Comment: @Simon: I don't see how you can't understand what I wrote. I said *the code you posted is not valid, so it will not compile. If it will not compile, it cannot be run. And if it cannot be run, it cannot cause the error you say it does. Please edit your post to provide the actual code you're using that will run and cause that error*, learning disability or not. Code that will not run will not cause a run-time exception. If you want help with your code, **post your real code**, which you still have not done.